# android BroadCastReceiver for location

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

in app i have a broadcastreceiver for my internet state:

```
public class InternetStateChange extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context context;

public InternetStateChange() {
    super();        
} 

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    InternetState.updateInternetListener(isInternetOn());
}

public boolean isInternetOn() {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo internet = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();  

     if (internet != null && internet.isConnected()) 
         return true; 
     return false;       
}

}
```

is it possible to do something like this for the location state ?
i don't mean to do it for location changes. i just want to be able to determine if the phone is even able to get it current location (like ther inernet.inConnected() method)

Comment: Do you mean detect if device has gps hardware and broadcast when it is turned on and off?  Similarly, detect if there is wireless network hardware and broadcast when it is turned on or off?

Comment: yes but not only gps. gps or location servicw provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html), there is a broadcast send when a Provider gets enabled/disabled. There is also a method to check all available location providers and if they are enabled.

Comment: do you mean the getPrividers(true) method ?

Comment: getProviders(boolean enabledOnly) gives you a list of all providers and with isProviderEnabled(String provider) you can check if the user has dem enabled or disabled. if the user changes one of the providers a Broadcast is send with KEY_PROVIDER_ENABLED to get the new configuration.